# MySQL query for all users NOT already following or already swiped

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following table's

```
USERS 
user_id /name/bio

FOLLOWERS 
user_id_fk/following_uid_fk

SWIPED
user_id_fk/ swiped_on_uid_fk
```

And I want to query for all the users that a user is not already following and has not already swiped on in the past and I'm having some trouble visualizing how it would go.

Here is my first attempt:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name
FROM users AS a, FOLLOWERS AS b, SWIPES AS c
WHERE a.user_id != b.swiped_on_user
  AND b.user_id_fk = '1'
  AND c.user_id_fk = '1'
  AND c.SWIPPED_user_id != a.user_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: In your query I think there is no `c.user_id_fk` or `c.SWIPPED_user_id` as your tables ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, u.name
FROM
    users As u
WHERE
    NOT u.user_id IN (
        SELECT
            user_id_fk
        FROM
            swiped)
    AND
    NOT u.user_id IN (
        SELECT
            user_id_fk
        FROM
            followers)
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this ? SELECT *
FROM users AS a, FOLLOWERS AS b, FRIEND_FINDER_SWIPES AS c
WHERE b.UID_FK = c.UID_FK
AND c.uid_fk =1
AND c.SWIPPED_UID_FK != a.uid
AND b.FOLLOWING_UID_FK != a.uid
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: I think when you want to query over a data that shouldn't list as data in another table you need to use `IN` not `CROSS JOIN` and `!=` ;).

Comment: Your query just returned  the same user x30 times for some reason

Comment: Either your misunderstanding what im trying to do or im completely lost bc that just returns myself, the query i posted in the comment appears to work but no way to know yet.

Comment: I edit my query to show `all the users that a user is not already following and has not already swiped` ;).